# Why Login in Azure SQL DB have privilege to select DB tables without linking user to DB?

Tags: authentication, azure-sql-database, privileges

There are some tables in DB1. I created Login MyLogin in Master DB without creating user for this(or I created but deleted). But now, at least I checked that there is no user with same SID with MyLogin. Why I still can have privilege to search the tables?

```
select * from sys.sysusers;   -- Check in DB1 
select * from sys.sql_logins; -- Check in Master DB
```

Comment: How do you login your Azure SQL database, with MyLogin or Server Admin account？

Comment: I login with MyLogin in SSMS/MS Access.

Comment: SELECT name, sid FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'MyLogin' only has the one resoult?How about drop the MyLogin before creating it,and try again?Please see here:[CREATE LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#examples-1) .

Comment: Is it due to I performed below steps before? The privileges won't be revoked after I changed back authorization to ServerAdmin? 
    ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE ::[DB1] TO [MyLogin]; then 
    ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE ::[DB1] TO [ServerAdmin];

Comment: Yeah,I think that's the most possible reason.ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE ::[DB1] TO [MyLogin] means that change the owner of the database to the login: MyLogin. To see [ALTER AUTHORIZATION for databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#AlterDB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we create login, we need to check if the login has exist.
Demo code:

```
DROP LOGIN TestLogin;  
GO  

CREATE LOGIN TestLogin   
WITH PASSWORD = 'SuperSecret52&&', SID = 0x241C11948AEEB749B0D22646DB1A19F2;  

SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'TestLogin';  
GO
```

Reference:[CREATE LOGIN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#a-creating-a-login-with-a-password-1).

After creating a login, the login can connect to SQL Database but only has the permissions granted to the public role.

But when you performed  `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE ::[DB1] TO [MyLogin]`,then  `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE ::[DB1] TO [ServerAdmin]`. It means that change the owner of a SQL Database to MyLogin.

Please see:[ALTER AUTHORIZATION for databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#AlterDB).

I think that's why you still can have privilege to search the tables.

Hope this helps.